# GWT Autobean JSON spec

Tags: json, gwt, rest, autobean

If I used Autobean on GWT client to serialise my POJO (sent out thro RequestBuilder) but I plan to use say, groovy, perl or php to service that request, I would need to know the serialization format of Autobean.

What is and where can I get the JSON format spec for Autobean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're documented [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean#JSON_structures).